# Scipy: do *not* stop solve_ivp/ode_int if rtol/atol not satisfied at set hmin

Tags: scipy, ode

When I run `scipy.solve_ivp` with LSODA or `scipy.odeint`, I set an rtol and atol as well as min_step. The desired behavior is to try to reach the fixed atol/rtol, but only let the step size go so small for memory and computation purposes. If it does not reach the tolerance with `h=hmin`, the integration should continue, perhaps with a warning. What actually seems to happen though is that if the tolerance is not reached with hmin, the integration is simply cancelled. Is there a way around this?? What I want is pseudo-adaptive time stepping, in the sense that I don't have to fix dt a priori, but also don't have to fully resolve the simulation. The reason I cannot achieve this with just making a larger rtol/atol is that the internal error estimators drastically overdo step refinement for moderately sharp gradients (there are no discontinuities or anything in my solutions), and allow very large time steps for smooth parts of the solution, so a large atol/rtol that doesn't break the integration at the sharper gradients allows way too large of a step on smoother parts of solution.

Comment: Are the components of your system at a common scale? Else it is necessary to give a per-component absolute tolerance.

Comment: ya, this is just a single component ODE. It does get quite stiff as it approaches the zero crossing, where I have a stop event, but I just want it to integrate to the event using hmin as accurately as it can